# How to initialize date type variable

Tags: apex, code

I am using date type variable

```
public Date arrivalDate {get;set;}
```

now my question is how we will initialize this variable in constructor in proper way, if I use this whats the meaning of 1,1,1.

```
arrivalDate = Date.newInstance(1,1,1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looked into `Date.newInstance()` method

It says

> [**newInstance(year, month, date)**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm)
>
> Constructs a Date from Integer representations of the year, month
>   (1=Jan), and day.

First parameter means it is year value, second parameter month value and lastly third one for day value

Comment: thanks, is there another way to initialize ?

Comment: @YogeshGupta for initialize this is the best option.. if you want another option then you can assign `Date.today()` for current date.. if you want prev week date then use `Date.TOday().addDays(-7)` OR if you want future dates then use like`Date.Today.addDays(7)` ... Here -7 means it will minus -7 from  current date and +7 means it will add into current date

Comment: @YogeshGupta Note that *most* classes use a simple constructor (new X(some params)). Date, DateTime, and Time data types happen to be exceptions to this rule. Honestly, not sure why they decided to do this, except perhaps to force developers to choose between local times and GMT times.

Comment: I just querying Date field and assign value in date variable, but in the UI its showing GMT format in text field, how can I convert it into Date 'dd-mm-yyyy'

Comment: @YogeshGupta can you ask this as a new question that will help other user as well

Comment: @sfdcweb, This is my new question                            http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118321/is-there-anyway-to-get-in-dd-mm-yyyy-or-mm-dd-yyyy-format