# Is there anyway to get in DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: apex, date

I just querying Date field and assign value in date variable

```
//Date variable
public Date arrivalDate {get;set;}
```

now I am quering date field and assigning value in variable

```
arrivalDate = QueryField;
```

In the inputselect box, its showing

```
Mon Apr 18 00:00:00 GMT 2016
```

In the UI its showing GMT format in text field, how can I convert it into Date 'dd-mm-yyyy'

Comment: public Date arrivalDate {get;set;}


//Initialise 
arrivalDate = System.today();



//Query
List<Account> acc = [Select Id , CreatedDate From Account limit 1];


arrivalDate = acc[0].CreatedDate;



//Arrival date is bind on VF page in input Text
{!arrivalDate}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason**: Salesforce store the dateTime value in database in GMT Format. When the dateTime display on standard page. It display in current user's time zone

Use in controller.. use `strConvertedDate` instead `a.CreatedDate`

DateTime format for current user

`CreatedDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy,HH:mm', UserInfo.getTimeZone().getID())` 
or

`CreatedDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy,HH:mm', UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString())`

```
String strConvertedDate = a.CreatedDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', UserInfo.getTimeZone().toString());
```

Use this string 'strConvertedDate' in VF

Comment: If use String type variable, then I will not able to show standard salesforce calendar on VF page, am I right ?

Comment: @YogeshGupta yes you can able to show the calender.. give a try I am not completely sure

Comment: while I am saving it giving an error                 Save error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Date].format(String, String)

Comment: @YogeshGupta can you add your code snippet in your question, what you have tried so far?

Comment: public Date arrivalDate {get;set;}


//Initialise 
arrivalDate = System.today();



//Query
List<Account> acc = [Select Id , CreatedDate From Account limit 1];


arrivalDate = acc[0].CreatedDate;



//Arrival date is bind on VF page in input Text
{!arrivalDate}

Comment: @YogeshGupta try to assign date to string with format