# Can anyone help to solve this issue, i want after converting datetime into string the value remains same

Tags: force.com

Can anyone help to solve this issue, i want  after converting `DateOfBirth` into string the value remains same.

Value is `- Sat Mar 01 00:00:00 EST 1980`

Comment: What exactly you are looking for? Please be descriptive in your Question with the Expectations & Actuals!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the Datetime Class format() method to convert a DateTime to the local timezone returns a String. For more info, go through the link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format_2

method

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date.valueOf(DATE_OF_BIRTH)`

it will take string argument and return Date Value

[Is there anyway to get in DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY format](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118321/is-there-anyway-to-get-in-dd-mm-yyyy-or-mm-dd-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 0):

Use valueOfGmt() function to convert date time to string

```
    string dob = string.valueOfGmt(DateOfBirth);
```

To convert String to Date time.

```
    Datetime Bday = Datetime.valueOfGMT(dob);
```